# Which package contains libc manpages?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, man, glibc

Which package does contain manpages for standard C functions? I have installed `glibc` and `gcc` but there are only POSIX manpages.

I mean manpages like `strlen`.

Comment: You want `sys-apps/man-pages`, as far as I can see here : https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Man_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had the `sys-apps/man-pages` installed but it was somehow broken. Reinstallation helped.

```
emerge -a sys-apps/man-pages
```